# reconstruct a text from the coordinates (abscissa and ordinate) of the characters on an image

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to reconstruct a Texte from an Image[image]

I Have already get the coordinates of the surrounded elements, here is the code :

```
NL = list()
for element in range(0, len(ajustX), 1):
    t= (dataList[element], ajustX[element], ajustY[element])
    NL.append(t)
NL = sorted(NL, key=lambda element: (element[2], element[1]))

print(type(ajustX), type(ajustY),type(NL),type(dataList))
print("\n"+"ajustX" +str(dataList)+"\n"+"X coordinates  "+str(ajustX)+"\n"+"Y coordinates  "+str(ajustY)+"\n"+"\n"+"NL:"+str(NL))
```

Here is the output I sorted the cordinates by X descending:

```
<class 'list'> <class 'list'> <class 'list'> <class 'list'>

letter list['T', 'O', 'T', 'A', 'L', '1', '2', '.', '1', 'O']
X coordinates  [28, 116, 205, 295, 384, 917, 1004, 1120, 1184, 1272]
Y coordinates  [33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 38, 38, 89, 38, 38]

NL:[('T', 28, 33), ('O', 116, 33), ('T', 205, 33), ('A', 295, 33), ('L', 384, 34), ('1', 917, 38), ('2', 1004, 38), ('1', 1184, 38), ('O', 1272, 38), ('.', 1120, 89)]
```

I am looking for a way to dynamically reconstruct the image  (even if I have an image with different coordinates) with the coordinates(NL) by saving in a file.

Code:

```
for element in range(0, len(NL), 1): 
    fichier = open("data.txt", "a")
    #Do something and write
```

In the saving the file I would like to have :

```
TOTAL 12.10
```

Thanks for your help and propositions

Comment: Is it python 2 or python 3? It would be great if you just leave one of tags or delete both of them and just leave python tag

Comment: python 3 please

Comment: someone has a solution ?